# react js - unable to check radio button since itt is read only because of check attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-group

I have situation where I am having radio button in the child component.
based on the data the questions and radio button will be populated.each set populated will contain two radio buttons.value of one radio button is yes and another one is no.

I am trying to check all the radio button with value yes on change of a check box.but still the user should be able to so individual manual selections.
but the radio buttons are rendered read only due to the attribute checked is added as it becomes a controlled.how to make the radio button editable or checkable manually

Comment: Could you include the code you have written so far in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it like this.

```
<input
  type="radio"
  name="radio1"
  checked={this.state.isChecked}
  onChange={() => this.setState({isChecked: true})}
/>

<input
  type="radio"
  name="radio1"
  checked={!this.state.isChecked}
  onChange={() => this.setState({isChecked: false})}
/>
```

You can set the initial state of **isChecked** true in your case.

When you add **checked** attribute to the input radio element, it becomes controlled, hence it is not editable. So, if you want to change it's state, you can do so by changing the value of **checked** attribute. I would suggest looking up **Controlled** and **Uncontrolled** elements in reactjs.